Changing enumerate globally depending on how many sublist exist
I use this code :
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\bfseries\arabic*)}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=4mm,label=\bfseries\alph*)}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item 
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

which gives me:

I would like it to be:

In other words, I would like the parenthesis to be a dot if there's a level 2 list.
How can I do it ?

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand you code to make it compilable?

I've replaced your hard to understand text by two images. I hope my interpretation of what you get and what you want is correct. If not, please replace the images.

The logic of your formatting objective has a temporal-precedence issue: In order to know whether to output "n)" or "n." upon encountering the n-th level-one \item directive, LaTeX must know whether or not that \item directive is followed by \begin{enumerate}. However, this knowledge is, by design, not available at the time \item is executed. Short of patching \item to include some \futurelet chicanery, I think it would be a lot easier to require \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.} and \setlist[enumerate,2]{left=-9pt,label=\bfseries\alph*)}.

I don't think it's a good idea, in terms of clarity of visual design, to modify the appearance of level-one enumerator labels depending on whether or not they're followed by a level-two enumerator label. To preserve visual clarity, why not use the suffix . for level-one enumerators throughout?

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype} % optional
\usepackage{lipsum}    % filler text

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{left=-9pt,label=\bfseries\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1][1-3]
\item 
   \begin{enumerate}
   \item \lipsum[1][4-6]
   \item \lipsum[1][7-10]
   \end{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1][11-14]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}

